# First Project with C++ and opencv and nothing can be found

Tags: opencv

I have visual studio 2017 and installed openCV 3.3.1 recently. I followed a tutorial for using opencv and it doesnt work. Can somebody help?

```
    #include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include<iostream>
#include"StdAfx.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
        int main()
        {
            Mat img = imread("lenna.png");
            namedWindow("image", WINDOW_NORMAL);
            imshow("image", img);
            waitKey(0);
            return 0;
        }
```

THis is the error I get when I want to compile. It cannot find anything:

[image]

Comment: have you added OpenCV path to project property sheet?? can't understand your errors as not in English.

Comment: Tank you for your message. Yes I did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>` this header file.

Comment: Thank you, now I am one step further. Nevertheless I get this error now:precompiled object not linked in; image may not run

Comment: Have you added path of Library to "Additional Include Directories" in property sheet? Add (Path to your OpenCV folder) and then \opencv\build\x64\vc14\lib to Additional Include Directories

Comment: in Visual studio 2017 I cannot find Additional Include Directories

Comment: Ok now I added but still this error: precompiled object not linked in; image may not run

Comment: I think there is error in adding paths in C/C++ and Linker (in Property sheet). Check this link: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html